# How to clean up a failed installation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, raspberry-pi

I was installing `flask` onto a Raspberry Pi using `pip-3.2`. There was some error (the output of a Html page about a list of syntax errors was dumped onto the screen). I then ran pip with `--upgrade` and it didn't get any better.

When I try to `import flask` I get more syntax errors.

How do I clean up and start again?

The following folders are in the `dist-packages` folder (from the date I guessed they were installed as part of flask):

```
flask
Flask-0.10.1-py3.2.egg-info
itsdangerous-0.24-py3.2.egg-info
jinja2
Jinja2-2.8-py3.2.egg-info
markupsafe
MarkupSafe-0.23-py3.2.egg-info
werkzeug
Werkzeug-0.11.2-py3.2.egg-info
Werkzeug-0.11.3-py3.2.egg-info
```

There is also a file: `itsdangerous.py`.

Does deleting all of the above achieve my aim?

Comment: DId you try `pip uninstall`? If you don't want such nasty problems, you should probably read about `virtualenv` and apply it in your work. It's very useful.

Comment: You tried installing flask, but there was HTML errors? Sounds like flask installed correctly if you are seeing HTML

Comment: Please share the errors you get when you try to import Flask.

Comment: Flask only supports 2.7 and 3.3+ - it uses constructs that are not available on 3.2.  Upgrade to 3.3+ or use 2.7 and things will just-work :-)

Comment: `pip uninstall` responded with `Successfully uninstalled Flask`, but the folders are still there. @dim: the errors are all Python syntax errors.  I didn't know there's a version 3.2 limitation.  Can I delete the folders to clean up?